# App is not available on Play Store in some tablet devices mostly with Android version 4.1.1

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

App is not available on Play Store in some tablet devices.

I searched about this issue but no solution solved my problem. I can't figure out why my app is not available on Play Store on some tablet devices. But when I try to search it in Google Play website using the browser, it is available and I was able to install it. I tried adding  tag and android:required="false" attribute as what others recommend but this doesn't solve the problem. This is the manifest of my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.companyname.appname"
android:versionCode="30"
android:versionName="1.0.20" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcer"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.ViewLogFragment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" />

    <receiver android:name="com.companyname.background.BootCompleteReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.companyname.background.ShutDownReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.companyname.background.TimeChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.companyname.background.DateChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.companyname.background.TimeZoneChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.companyname.background.SyncAndUpdateService" />
    <service android:name="com.companyname.background.AutoSendBackUpService" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: According to this a camera is required. Do all the rejected tablets have a camera?

Comment: Yes, actually I can install my app on rejected tablets via browser. By copying and pasting the URL to the browser, I can search it but when I search it via Play Store, it shows no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's no error on the manifest. It just took 3 days for all the devices to see my app. When I uploaded my app on the Google Play, after 2-3 hours it is already available for some devices but it took 3 days for other devices. There's no issue on the android version or on the manifest. Just make sure you check out [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) before uploading your app on the Play Store as what [SirChristian123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648039/sirchristian123) adviced.

Answer (score 0):

I actually does not seems something wrong with the code, You should be careful with the camera feature like Henry said because Google is not going to show it if a device does not support a camera. Sometimes it can confuses Google though.

Check this out and see if something in your code that you did not posted here is the problem:

This is the official information about Filters in Google Play:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll double check my code for any possible cause of my problem.